# How can I parse out unwanted text data from a field

Tags: t-sql, ssms-2014

I am using sequel server management studio 2014, and I am wondering how I can parse out what is extraneous data for a select query.  I do not wish to modify the data, only to grab what I need from it for a SSRS data source, to automate a query.  The query would look like what is listed below.

An example of a value in the comments field is listed below
'Based on PO #105680 - Thomas Test GRPO Reciept Validation query test'

Ideally I only want the value '105680' so I can use it as a lookup reference.  Any help would be appreciated as always.

```
SELECT
   [DocEntry]
  ,[DocNum]
  ,[DocType]
  ,[CANCELED]
  ,[Comments]
  FROM [Billy].[dbo].[OPDN]
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more vague about your algorithm for determining the _good bits_ in any given string? Might that change from time to time, e.g. wanting the company name rather than the P.O. #? And what have you tried?

Comment: Greetings, I apologize for being vague, I really tried to be specific and missed the mark.  There is logic in place that imputes the value 'Based on PO#' and also logic that includes a space then a hyphen, and the remarks after.  My ideal parse would only include the data after the pound sign and prior to the space before the -.  If further explanation is required please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CHARINDEX to find the PO # in the text and then SUBSTRING to parse out the number as long as the format is consistent.

```
;WITH TEMP AS (SELECT  'Based on PO #105680 - Thomas Test GRPO Reciept Validation query test' AS comment )

SELECT comment, 
    CASE WHEN TEMP.comment LIKE '%PO #%' THEN SUBSTRING(TEMP.comment, CHARINDEX('PO #', TEMP.comment) + 4, CHARINDEX('PO #', TEMP.comment, CHARINDEX(' ', TEMP.comment) + 1) - 4) END AS PO_NUM
FROM TEMP
```

Your query would be something like

```
SELECT
   [DocEntry]
  ,[DocNum]
  ,[DocType]
  ,[CANCELED]
  ,[Comments]
  ,CASE WHEN Comments LIKE '%PO #%' THEN SUBSTRING(Comments, CHARINDEX('PO #', Comments) + 4, CHARINDEX('PO #', Comments, CHARINDEX(' ', Comments) + 1) - 4) END AS PO_NUM
FROM [Billy].[dbo].[OPDN]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, would I include the example above after the initial query and execute all togather?

Comment: @Thomas - I think you only really need the CASE statement to use for your field.

Comment: Thank you my friend, I appreciate your assistance very much.  I will try this afternoon and mark as solved, once I can validate it works.